# Xpath regex functionality

Tags: php, regex, xpath

So i have the bellow code

```
<?php

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML('<body>
        <label>    Foobar   </label>
        <label>    Foobar + Foo   </label>
     </body>');

    $xPath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xPath->query("//body//*[contains(text(), 'Foobar')]");


    foreach($elements as $e)
    {
        echo $e->nodeName . ': ' . $e->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

And am trying to capture `Foobar` with spaces only, which would look like this with regex:

```
^\s*Foobar\s*$
```

But with the current code i have, i end up with this result:

```
label:      Foobar 
label:      Foobar + Foo
```

And when i try `//body//*[text()='Foobar']` the result is `null`.
Also the spaces around `Foobar` is not consistent, And i dont want to inject any php function into it (`$xPath->register*`)

[Code Sample](https://3v4l.org/HtaTU)

Comment: Give the [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function a whirl. For example, `//body//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'Foobar']`.

Comment: See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/KQNsU) showing the above xpath expression result.

Comment: @salathe I think you should post an answer. Or please find a question to close with.